# Eclipse Google Plug-In doesn't start server for web application

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I want to try the Google Eclipse plug-in for the Google App Engine, but I get stuck in the tutorial...

I want to start the web application from the Google tutorial, but when I click on "RUN AS > Web Application", I only see this message on the console:

```
Usage: <dev-appserver> [options] <war directory>

Options:
 --help, -h                 Show this help message and exit.
 --server=SERVER            The server to use to determine the latest
  -s SERVER                   SDK version.
 --address=ADDRESS          The address of the interface on the local machine
  -a ADDRESS                  to bind to (or 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
 --port=PORT                The port number to bind to on the local machine.
  -p PORT
 --sdk_root=root            Overrides where the SDK is located.
 --disable_update_check     Disable the check for newer SDK versions.
```

What's the problem? It seems like the command to start the server is wrong, but I haven't edited it... can someone help?

Comment: I had the same problem but i finded this [Why can not i run a google app engine project on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22131445)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It is because your launch configuration file (location: WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches)is corrupt. All you need to do to solve this problem is to delete the existing launch configuration (in Run > Run configurations)

Comment: If it still doesn't work after deleting the launch configuration give eclipse a restart, that worked for me :)

Comment: Run > Run configurations > Web Application > right click in your project's name > Delete

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Eclipse Project or GAE SDK has spaces in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information to what's already been said.

You need to install "m2eclipse" otherwise you will not have the "run as" option.