# Unable to start google app engine server

Tags: java, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse Google Plug-In doesn't start server for web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712270/eclipse-google-plug-in-doesnt-start-server-for-web-application)

I am unable to start the google app engine server from eclipse.

It was working fine for me.
Whenever I go to "Run->Debug as->google web application", it used to start the server.

But now I am getting following message.

```
Usage: <dev-appserver> [options] <war directory>

Options:
 --help, -h                 Show this help message and exit.
 --server=SERVER            The server to use to determine the latest
  -s SERVER                   SDK version.
 --address=ADDRESS          The address of the interface on the local machine
  -a ADDRESS                  to bind to (or 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
 --port=PORT                The port number to bind to on the local machine.
  -p PORT
 --sdk_root=root            Overrides where the SDK is located.
 --disable_update_check     Disable the check for newer SDK versions.
```

Thanks in advance.

Similar question have been asked before also: 
[Eclipse Google Plug-In doesn't start server for web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712270/eclipse-google-plug-in-doesnt-start-server-for-web-application)

Comment: What version of the SDK? Of the Google Plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: I am using version 1.6.0(Google Plugin)

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of the one you linked to.

Comment: @NickJohnson Yes Nick, But nobody answered that question.

Comment: @shantanu That doesn't matter, I'm afraid - duplicates aren't allowed. You should try drawing peoples' attention to the existing question.