# Google App Engine Debug Server (local host) won't start

Tags: google-app-engine, settings, localhost, config

I just installed the latest GAE SDK and created a basic hello world project.  I tried to debug the server locally and came across this in the console.  Anyone else have this issue?

2012-05-06 01:20:33.770 java[467:407] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2012-05-06 01:20:33.772 java[467:407] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
Usage:  [options]

Options:
 --help, -h                 Show this help message and exit.
 --server=SERVER            The server to use to determine the latest
  -s SERVER                   SDK version.
 --address=ADDRESS          The address of the interface on the local machine
  -a ADDRESS                  to bind to (or 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
 --port=PORT                The port number to bind to on the local machine.
  -p PORT
 --sdk_root=root            Overrides where the SDK is located.
 --disable_update_check     Disable the check for newer SDK versions.
 --generated_dir=dir        Set the directory where generated files are created.

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: Looks like I didn't have the latest SDK 1.6.5 installed.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads

Comment: anyusers-MacBook-Air:platform-tools anyuser$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-11M3646)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)  I installed 1.6.5 of the SDK but I'm still having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a similar thread.  My Run Config file was corrupt.

"It is because your launch configuration file (location: WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches)is corrupt. All you need to do to solve this problem is to delete the existing launch configuration (in Run > Run configurations)"

Here's the link with the answer also.

[Eclipse Google Plug-In doesn't start server for web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712270/eclipse-google-plug-in-doesnt-start-server-for-web-application)

-J