# error when trying to run Google app engine- Usage: <dev-appserver> [options] <war directory>

Tags: java, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse Google Plug-In doesn't start server for web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712270/eclipse-google-plug-in-doesnt-start-server-for-web-application)

I am getting this error message when trying to run GAE

Usage:  [options]

Options:
 --help, -h                 Show this help message and exit.
 --server=SERVER            The server to use to determine the latest
  -s SERVER                   SDK version.
 --address=ADDRESS          The address of the interface on the local machine
  -a ADDRESS                  to bind to (or 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
 --port=PORT                The port number to bind to on the local machine.
  -p PORT
 --sdk_root=root            Overrides where the SDK is located.
 --disable_update_check     Disable the check for newer SDK versions.
 --generated_dir=dir        Set the directory where generated files are created.

what does that mean? I'm trying to run on default configurations,
How to configure the launch?

I tried to erase the launch configuration, and now I'm getting a new error message:

When I erased the launch configuration , I got a new error message when debugging:

Missing required argument 'module[s]'
Google Web Toolkit 2.4.0
DevMode [-noserver] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-workDir dir] module[s]

where 
  -noserver        Prevents the embedded web server from running
  -port            Specifies the TCP port for the embedded web server (defaults to 8888)
  -whitelist       Allows the user to browse URLs that match the specified regexes (comma or space separated)
  -blacklist       Prevents the user browsing URLs that match the specified regexes (comma or space separated)
  -logdir          Logs to a file in the given directory, as well as graphically
  -logLevel        The level of logging detail: ERROR, WARN, INFO, TRACE, DEBUG, SPAM, or ALL
  -gen             Debugging: causes normally-transient generated types to be saved in the specified directory
  -bindAddress     Specifies the bind address for the code server and web server (defaults to 127.0.0.1)
  -codeServerPort  Specifies the TCP port for the code server (defaults to 9997)
  -server          Specify a different embedded web server to run (must implement ServletContainerLauncher)
  -startupUrl      Automatically launches the specified URL
  -war             The directory into which deployable output files will be written (defaults to 'war')
  -deploy          The directory into which deployable but not servable output files will be written (defaults to 'WEB-INF/deploy' under the -war directory/jar, and may be the same as the -extra directory/jar)
  -extra           The directory into which extra files, not intended for deployment, will be written
  -workDir         The compiler's working directory for internal use (must be writeable; defaults to a system temp dir)
and 
  module[s]        Specifies the name(s) of the module(s) to host

Comment: How, exactly, are you "trying to run GAE"? What is your exact command line?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to specify that I'm using the java plug-in for Eclipse, so I'm getting this error when trying to run it on Eclipse!

Comment: What version of GPE, and what version of the SDK? Newer GPEs might be assuming newer SDKs.

Comment: Eclipse SDK v3.6.2 and GPE v2.6.1 !

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? Do I have to change any configuration ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the AppEngine SDK version.

Comment: I found this response : [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712270/eclipse-google-plug-in-doesnt-start-server-for-web-application)
I tried it, doesn't work for me!