# Why can not i run a google app engine project on localhost?

Tags: google-app-engine, swt, dev-appserver

I am using macbook pro for development. I just installed eclipse indigo. Google app engine Java SDK is 1.8.2. I am trying to run an appengine project on localhost. But i am getting the following error:

```
 2013-08-04 13:14:03.193 java[2146:707] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
 2013-08-04 13:14:03.194 java[2146:707] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
 Usage: <dev-appserver> [options] <app directory>

 Options:
  --help, -h                 Show this help message and exit.
  --server=SERVER            The server to use to determine the latest
  -s SERVER                   SDK version.
  --address=ADDRESS          The address of the interface on the local machine
  -a ADDRESS                  to bind to (or 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
  --port=PORT                The port number to bind to on the local machine.
  -p PORT
  --sdk_root=DIR             Overrides where the SDK is located.
  --disable_update_check     Disable the check for newer SDK versions.
  --generated_dir=DIR        Set the directory where generated files are created.
  --jvm_flag=FLAG            Pass FLAG as a JVM argument. May be repeated to
                          supply multiple flags.
```

I googled a lot but any solution i found did not work for me. I uploaded app on appengine and opened it using url. And its working fine there. Can anybody tell me why is it not working on my mac. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed Appengine Eclipse Plugin?

Comment: yes. how can i create a new app engine project without installing it.

Comment: The plugin is optional, you can manually create all the files required and deploying them with appcfg by command-line.

Answer (score 8):

The problem occurs when using blank spaces in the project name.

"Run Configurations> Arguments > Program Arguments", insert quotation marks in the project path. i.e.:

```
--port=8888 --disable_update_check {PATH}\My Project
```

To:

```
--port=8888 --disable_update_check "{PATH}\My Project"
```

Comment: You save my Life sir. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. Strangely, the default arguments are incorrect. Remove the first and the third element and it works.

Finally, you should have something like that under: Debug Configurations... > Web Application > project1 > Arguments > Program Arguments

```
--port=8888 /Users/user1/java/project1/war
```