# Google App Engine: Connection Refused Error

Tags: ubuntu, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, localhost

I have set my GAE web app with all the appropriate endpoints and deployed it locally on my ubuntu pc. I get connected to my home network, I found my computer's local IP, selected the correct port (8888 is the default for GAE web apps) tried to connect (from Chrome and my android device) but no luck. I get

`Google Chrome's connection attempt to 192.168.1.2 was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.`

`Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Where should I look? Is this a GAE, network or Ubuntu issue?

Comment: have you simply tried localhost:8888 or localhost:8080

Comment: Localhost works when I am accessing the server from the pc that hosts it, but I want to access the server from an android device, connected to the same local network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set the  --address=192.168.1.2 (for java)  (--host=192.168.1.2 for python) flag when you startup the app

Comment: Could you please tell me how to pass this argument to the server? Also do I have to do anything on my client app? Like change any constant?

Comment: Are you using python, dev_appserver.py and appcfg.py?

Comment: I use Java, I haven't used any python scrips (don't know if app engine generates something) I've deployed a default implementation of a java web app.

Comment: For java, it's the `--address=` flag.  See edit.  More at:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Running_the_Development_Web_Server

Comment: How do I use this flag? I tried Run Configurations-> Arguments 
--address=127.0.0.1 but it doens't seem to work.

Comment: Are you trying to access it from a browser on the same computer that is running the app?  If so, then 127.0.0.1 is fine, and you should use the url `127.0.0.1:8888`.  If trying to access from another computer on the network, then set `--address=192.168.1.2`, and point the browser to `192.168.1.2:8888`.  The `address` flag is the url you want to use.

Comment: I am accessing the server from a different machine, on the same LAN network though. When I set the `--address=192.168.1.2` I cannot launch the server. I get this: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712270/eclipse-google-plug-in-doesnt-start-server-for-web-application`

Comment: I think you pasted the wrong URL.  Are you using Eclipse?  If so, you can set the server address there.

Comment: Yes, I use eclipse. I pasted the exact address as you typed in to Run configurations-> arguments-> program arguments leaving just a space within the previous argument.

Comment: I am referring the paste in your comment above.  What is the error?  Sorry, but I cannot spend much more time on this.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.1.2 is generally the router address, although it's possible you have set it as your local computer IP.

The --address flag will work as long as you have the correct LAN IP address, in your case, I think you got the wrong one.

If you are on Windows, go to your cmd and type ipconfig. Look for the field IPv4 Address, it should have your local IP address that looks "similar" to 198.128.1.2.

Let me know if that works for you, thanks.